# A basic question in FOL

Tags: logic

First of all I am new(poor) in Logic. I am  doing a background reading and I stopped at the Completeness theorem: Any consistent set of sentences $\gamma$ of first order language
$L$ has a model of cardinality at most max($|\gamma|$, $\aleph_{0}$).
What  is  meant by the cardinality of $|\gamma|$(I mean let us say $\gamma$ contains 3 sentences then $|\gamma|$ = 3?( I know what cardinality means in Set theory).

In fact, I found out that I dont really understand the stuff  I read before reaching this point. Formulas and sentences are introduced before introducing structures! and this is confusing me somehow. However, please could you give me an example of uncountable set
of sentences?

Comment: Take a language with a constant $c_e$ for every real number $e\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the set $\{c_e\neq c_d : e\neq d\land e,d\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is uncountable.

Comment: $|\gamma|$ is just the cardinality of $\gamma$ as a set. We subsume an ambient (usually naive) set theory is present to be able to talk about this. As to the rest of your question, I don't really understand it. It might help to disclose your source work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to address your general concern, but the most common example of an uncountable set of sentences involves an uncountable language (which, of course, it must).  So consider an uncountable set of constants $\{c_\alpha\}$ and the set of sentences $\{ c_\alpha \not= c_\beta : \alpha\not=\beta\}$.  **Edit:** Apostolos beat me to it :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the language contains $\kappa$ symbols then there are $\kappa^{<\omega}=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\kappa^n=\max\{\kappa,\aleph_0\}$ formulas and sentences we can write. So if $L$ is a finite, or even countably infinite language, we can only write countably many sentences. So in order to have an uncountable set of sentences, one has to have an uncountable language.

For example the language which has a constant symbol $c_r$ for every $r\in\Bbb R$ is uncountable. Then you can write the uncountable set of sentences $\{c_r\neq c_s\mid r,s\in\Bbb R\}$, that is we assert that all these constants are distinct.

Comment: First I dont know how to mark your answer as the 'best' answer.However, Could you please define " precisely" what you mean by a Language.( I looked over the internet, but non-single precise mathematical definition I could come up with!

Comment: Language is sometimes referred to as "signature". It is simply the alphabet for writing the formulas.